# Batch file start up a computer

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am not an batch file expert but i trying to write a program for my business that requires a batch file to turn on and turn off computers according to a schedule.

I did a research and I have found a lot of examples of using batch file to turn off a pc after X minutes. However, I could not find any example of batch file turning on a pc according to a schedule (for example I want my computer to start at 8:00 pm OR after 5 hours etc...) 
is there such a code for this purpose?

I appreciate your answers

Comment: hmmmm... and where would this process be running while your computer is turned off?

Comment: that sounds a bit impossible to do since windows has to be running for a batch file to run...however you could schedule a wake up event for a machine that is sleeping in task scheduler

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to enable Wake-On-LAN (http://windows7-issues.blogspot.com/2011/03/wake-on-lan-wol-for-windows-7-made-easy.html) on your NIC and firewall.  Then you can turn the remote computer on using another computer, using the Wake-On-LAN "magic packet."

Not sure if it can be scripted using Batch, but you would use a tool like this: http://www.matcode.com/wol.htm from the remote computer to turn on the desired PC.

Answer (score 0):

The computer BIOS may have a category to start the computer at a certain time.